# Java category missing in Apache Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

So I installed Apache Netbeans. Installed some of the plugins and instead of just seeing the Java folder in the categories when I want to create a new Project, I see this:

[image]

What is Gradle, Ant, and Maven? I am not familiar with Java and wanted to study the language, but I have no idea of what these are.

I keep seeing that I need to have certain plug ins installed and active.

Here they are.

[image]

Comment: [1] See [Ant vs Maven vs Gradle](https://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle) for an overview. [2] As it stands your question is far too general and broad, and would require a lengthy answer. [3] See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for clarification. [4] As a separate matter, do not post screen shots using links. Instead, embed the images within your question.

Answer (score 3):

Ant, Maven and Gradle are Java build tools. You don't really need to know the exact differences though.

#### Java with Ant

The "Java with Ant" option uses NetBeans' own internal project format (based on [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)). In older NetBeans versions this category was simply called "Java"

If you don't need to share your project with non-NetBeans users, use that option.

You will have to manage dependent libraries yourself (download, add them to the project) unless you are only using libraries and frameworks that are bundled with NetBeans. The turnaround times (the time it takes between you hit "Run" and the application actually starts) are the shortest with this option, as Maven and Gradle add substantial overhead to that.

#### Java with Maven

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a standardized dependency and build management tool. A project defined with Maven can be used by everybody else as it automatically manages (and downloads) any dependency. 
Use that option if you know you need to share your project with other people (e.g. hand it in your school or university).

#### Java with Gradle

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/) is yet another build tool, which also manages dependencies for your and has more flexibility than Maven. However the build scripts are less standardized than in Maven. But that is also a good option if you know that you need to share your project with other people. 
Unless you are using NetBeans 11.1 (which is currently in Beta) I would *not* use this option as Gradle support in older versions is not as good as Ant or Maven support.

---

You might want to go through the tutorials on the NetBeans homepage:

- http://netbeans.apache.org/help/index.html